# How to make CSS "execute" when user is viewing that part of the page?

Tags: javascript, css

Similar to how some CSS can be executed by events like using `:hover`, how could I make the same code execute when the user is simply viewing that part of the page? Example: user scrolls down to footer, and some nice CSS effects execute. I'll add a javascript tag to this thread incase that would be needed.

Edit from comment: Some more context...I have a button with a bunch of CSS effects already in place, and was just looking to "activate" them upon viewing.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript for that.

Comment: You can use the WOW.js library to do that: http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: Some more context...I have a button with a bunch of CSS effects already in place, and was just looking to "activate" them upon viewing.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not made for that. You will have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in CSS. You will need JavaScript.

<strike>If you are using jQuery, [it offers a `:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).</strike> EDIT: jQuery's `:visible` selector is not the same as "in viewport", as @mplungjan pointed out. @mplungjan also found this page on viewport selectors for jQuery: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: I do not think :visible is the same as "in viewport"

Answer (score 1):

You could check out this JS library, because it's not possible with CSS.

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html